# uilabel from custom tableview cell is not displayed in tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uitableview

I have created a table view controller and custom cell .I have created a new tableviewCell  file which has outlets for the labels in the custom cell .

I have imported the tableviewcell class in the tableviewController and tried to assign value from an array to the cell by the following code :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
}
```

cell.name.text= [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

**cell.name** -----------(name which is the uilabel in the tableviewcell class is not displayed ,even in the help it does not exist! ,I have no idea why  )

The code below works by tagging the label

```
    // Configure the cell...

//    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:111];
//              label.text= [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

My query is how do I make the outlet part work without tagging and why uilabel is not displayed in the tableviewCOntroller ?

Please help me out.I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your custom cell's class name is "MyCustomTableCell" which subclassing from UITableViewCell then code must look like this

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
MyCustomTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MyCustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
 }
```

then you can access it's property

```
cell.name = @"cell name";
```

Comment: I have another addon query - What is the difference between :MyCustomTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: And MyCustomTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: I have seen both online and dont jnow which one to use for the above example currently going with the above code.Please tell me the difference ?

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath is new iOS 6 register-and-dequeue system. I think it's way to tell the iOS that use new feature on iOS, indexPath doesn't really matter... this method never return nil, it will always return something..

Comment: Is it to eradicate this :( sometimes when I scroll up and down the cell are re-organised in a different(random) pattern like : 1,2,3,4,5 : would be 2,5,4,1,3 something like that.How do I resolve that .Thanks again for your time.)

Comment: You only need to set the cell's property when it's created.. because you are using resuableCells with all same name "Cell"... so what you can try is change CellIdendifier to unique for each cell.  CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row]; and you can see how it works..

Comment: so ios6 is taking care about that problem I guess.I had seen this problem without using indexpath.Is is true about what I said >?

Answer (score 3):

Remember to loadNib:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
 MyCustomTableCell *cell = (MyCustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyCustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
       // UINib *theNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomTableCell" bundle:nil];
       // cell = [[theNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    }
```

Comment: I have another addon query - What is the difference between :MyCustomTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
And MyCustomTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
 
I have seen both online and dont jnow which one to use for the above example currently going with the above code.Please tell me the difference ?

Comment: Sir and one more thing sometimes when I scroll up and down the cell are re-organised in a different(random) pattern like : 1,2,3,4,5 : would be 2,5,4,1,3 something like that.How do I resolve that .Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Check UITableView.h, you'll see the different between 2methods.One for iOS5, another for iOS6

Comment: Can you explain briefly PLEASE ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26127/discussion-between-james-patrick-and-aa)